# How to send photo via Telegram Bot with file path?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to send a photo through my Telegram bot, but am getting an error. I have the file path of the photo on my computer. Maybe I am not putting the file path in correctly. The error I get is:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`.
```

Which is referring to right before the path name. This is the code I have:

```
import requests
import json

bot_token = 'XXXXXX'
chat_id = "-100YYYYYY"
file = "C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop\Capture.PNG"

message = ('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+ bot_token + '/sendPhoto?chat_id=' 
           + chat_id + 'photo=' + file)
send = requests.get(message)
```

Comment: The error message here points to '\U'. The backslash '\' character in python is used to refer to special characters, such as the newline character '\n'. You need to double the backslash. "C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Capture.PNG". I don't think the request you are building will work. The server api.telegram.org does not have Capture.PNG, so it is useless to give the path, you need to find the way to send the actual image. Wait for someone with knowledge of the telegram API to answer or try to read the telegram documentation.

Comment: How do I add the photo to the Telegram server? And then what would that file_id be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you should upload file using the telegram sendPhoto endpoint in python.

```
import requests
import json

bot_token = 'BOT TOKEN'
chat_id = "CHAT ID"
file = r"C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Desktop\Capture.PNG"

files = {
    'photo': open(file, 'rb')
}

message = ('https://api.telegram.org/bot'+ bot_token + '/sendPhoto?chat_id=' 
           + chat_id)
send = requests.post(message, files = files)
```

Answer (score -2):

In reply to the answer, I used the above code, but the image quality is just bad and i cannot understand the images contents clearly. Image is of a screenshot of my laptop screen which has a 1080p resolution

Comment: Hi @Vindictive, and thank you for contributing. Your post does not answer the raised question but is a comment to another answer. Please consider moving your post as a comment. Note that answers are sorted as a function of their reputation, so one should avoid using "the above" in order to make reference to another answer. Finally, the image you are making reference to is missing.