# uploading file to telegram bot using the query string

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to upload file to my telegram bot but it doesn't work...

I tried this:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot~MY_BOT_TOKEN~/sendDocument?chat_id=~MY_ID~&document=C:/testing.j[g`

but than it showed:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified"}
```

what can I do?

Comment: what are you using to make the request?

Comment: right now I'm trying to do this via my browser, in the end I'll use python

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61463943/11984670

Comment: you can't use the browser's url bar to upload files. You need to a tool or library that can send a `POST` request to the end point. ('requests' lib in python for instance as in the above answer I've shared)

Comment: glad it worked. you may consider upvoting the answer (on the answer page) to mark it as useful.